Replace mget with env argument in update join
I'm starting to learn how to use env argument in data.table, but I'm having some problems.
Suppose the following update join
library(data.table)

X <- data.table(id = 1:5, L = letters[1:5])
Y <- data.table(id = 3:5, L = c(NA, "g", "h"), N = c(10, NA, 12))

ucols <- names(Y)[names(Y) %in% names(X)]
X[Y, on = .(id), (ucols) := mget(paste0("i.",ucols))]

How I can do this using env instead of mget? I tried to do the following but it didn't worked
X[Y, on = .(id), (ucols) := paste0("i.", ucols), env = list(ucols = as.list(ucols))]


Something like this works: uq = quote(.(id = i.id, L = i.L)); X[Y, on = .(id), (ucols) := uq, env = list(uq = uq)][] but I assume you don't want to provide uq manually such as I did here.

This do the work:
X[Y, on = .(id), (ucols) := ucols2, 
  env = list(ucols = I(ucols), ucols2 = as.list(paste0("i.",ucols)))]

Explanation:
substitute2() converts lists to list calls and character strings to names
So while the normal substitute
substitute( {x}, env = list(x = as.list(paste0("i.",ucols))))

produces
{
    list("i.id", "i.L")
}

the enhaced substitute2
substitute2( {x}, env = list(x = as.list(paste0("i.",ucols))))

produces
{
    list(i.id, i.L)
}

Which is what you want on the RHS of :=
(in the last case list is a call, a language object, while base R substitute produces a plain list.)

Find one way to solve your problem below:
X[Y, (ucols) := icols, on=.(id) , env=list(icols = as.list(paste0("i.", ucols)))]

